# rendering a different template in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, templates, rendering, ruby-on-rails-3.2

i've a view with a

```
<%= render :partial => @list.items%>
```

To show the this command called the _item.html.erb. Right?

```
<div class="well">
  <%= image_tag item.photo.url(:small) %><br>
  <b>Title</b> <%= item.title %><br />
  <b>Description</b> <%= item.description %>
</div>
```

This works fine.
Now i have an other template called `_ilist.html.erb` where i need some of this data.
I try to render this by adding the template option. But the other template will not used. The first template will called anytime.

```
<%= render :partial => @list.items, :template => 'items/ilist' %>
```

Is there any option to call the other _ilist-template?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need:

```
<%= render :partial => 'items/ilist', :collection => @list.items, :as => :item %>
```

Comment: Thanks thats it. But now i get an error on line two (for a test i copied the item.html.erb)
`<div class="well-form">
<%= image_tag item.photo.url%><br>
<b>Wunsch:</b> <%= item.title %><br />
<b>Beschreibung:</b> <%= item.description %>

</div>
<p>Reservieren</p>`
`undefined local variable or method `item' for #<#<Class:0x000000032c0e40>:0x007fcb645f8390>`

Comment: In your render statement also pass in ":as => :item"

Comment: Thanks a lot it runs fine. Now i learn what this statement means